# Type downcasting in Swift

Tags: swift, casting

Is there a difference (and if so what's the underlying principle?) between downcasting `variable as! NSString` and downcasting `variable as NSString!`?

Comment: From practical use there seems to be no difference in use from what I can see. They are both to deal with forced unwrapping of optional variables.

Comment: @Chackle: Not quite. Sometimes, Xcode might complain about using `as` if it thinks that it is absolutely impossible to perform a downcast. For example, the following code will yield an error: `struct Foo { }; var foo = Foo(); foo as NSString!`

Comment: In Swift 1.2 version, they quit the `as` operator, leaving just `as!` and `as?` so, now we have a forced and a conditional downcast. Now there is no place for ambiguity.

Comment: @gabuh: They most certainly have not quit the `as` operator.

Comment: @VatsalManot oops.. I see I was wrong... I just changed my mind to use the new forced downcast and thought the old was not available. Thanks!

Comment: @gabuh: Always read the release notes! :)

Answer (score 4):

- `variable as! NSString`

is forced **downcasting** of a variable to `NSString` and will raise run time error if `variable` is not `NSString`.

- `variable as NSString!`

Since Swift 1.2 operator `as` can only be used for **upcasting**, so above code will raise compile time error, unless `variable` is known to be a subclass of `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is known better as *downcasting*. You can read Apple's documentation on this matter [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

> A constant or variable of a certain class type may actually refer to
>   an instance of a subclass behind the scenes. Where you believe this is
>   the case, you can try to downcast to the subclass type with a type
>   cast operator (as? or as!).
>
> Because downcasting can fail, the type cast operator comes in two
>   different forms. The conditional form, as?, returns an optional value
>   of the type you are trying to downcast to. The forced form, as!,
>   attempts the downcast and force-unwraps the result as a single
>   compound action.
>
> Use the conditional form of the type cast operator (as?) when you are
>   not sure if the downcast will succeed. This form of the operator will
>   always return an optional value, and the value will be nil if the
>   downcast was not possible. This enables you to check for a successful
>   downcast.
>
> Use the forced form of the type cast operator (as!) only when you are
>   sure that the downcast will always succeed. This form of the operator
>   will trigger a runtime error if you try to downcast to an incorrect
>   class type.